# Get variable from parameter file in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

How to get a variable in symfony2 controller from parameters file **app/config/parameters.yml**.

```
parameters:
    host_name: www.mydomain.con
```

Comment: [Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html) is pretty useful for your use-case

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will get like this

```
$this->container->getParameter('host_name');
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
$this->container->getParameter('host_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
$this->container->getParameter('host_name');

And if you want in twig then try like below

Add in app/config/config.yml like: 

twig:
    globals:
    host_name: '%host_name%'

and in twig file use as normal variable like:

{{host_name}}
```

Enkoy!